# how to ignore specific values in group by in sql

Tags: sql, null, group-by

So the query I made:

```
    select distinct id, str_replace(convert(varchar,start_time,102),'.','-') [date], 
    min(convert(varchar(8), start_time, 108)) [start time],
    max(convert(varchar(8), start_time, 108)) [end time],
    max(o) [o],
    max(a) [a], case when error_msg != '(null)' then error_msg end [error?],
    from table group by id order by id desc
```

Brings back this:

```
   id     date      start time   end time   o   a   error?
------------------------------------------------------------     
7338971 2012-06-09  11:06:20    11:06:20    2   5   (null)
7338970 2012-06-09  11:06:08    11:06:59    362 725 Yes
7338970 2012-06-09  11:06:08    11:06:59    362 725 (null)
```

where the data is grouped by id. However, there are two entries for id# 7338970  because there is a null and an actual error. Is there any way to ignore the null and only display one row for 7338970, displaying yes for the error column?
So it would be:

```
    id     date      start time   end time   o   a   error?
------------------------------------------------------------     
7338971 2012-06-09  11:06:20    11:06:20    2   5   (null)
7338970 2012-06-09  11:06:08    11:06:59    362 725 Yes
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the original SQL query.

Comment: What rdbms are you using? If there is just one row for an ID you want to see it whether or not it's error is null?

Comment: I'm using sybase 5.5 and yes, I would like to see if its null or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment "if error is null, then it should show null in the error column":

```
select distinct id, str_replace(convert(varchar,start_time,102),'.','-') [date], 
min(convert(varchar(8), start_time, 108)) [start time],
max(convert(varchar(8), start_time, 108)) [end time],
max(o) [o],
max(a) [a], case when error_msg != '(null)' then isnull(error_msg,'null') end [error?],
from table 
group by id order by id desc
```

Comment: I would like to see if the error is null if there was no error in the file's travels however.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying.  What does "if there error is null if there was no error" mean?

Comment: if error is null, then it should show null in the error column, not exclude it entirely

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

`and error is not null`

to your query.

Comment: I would like to see if error is null though if no error exists for the id